# Android: AndroidX back compatibility

Tags: android

I want to use AndroidX library, but in the official Google developer website, they said it works with Android 9 and SDK 28, and I’m using Android 6 with SDK 23, can I use AndroidX in my project? Or should I continue to use support library ? I found no information on the Internet.
Thanks.

Comment: Bases on Android docs : AndroidX is a major improvement to the original Android Support Library. Like the Support Library, AndroidX ships separately from the Android OS and provides backwards-compatibility across Android releases. AndroidX fully replaces the Support Library by providing feature parity and new libraries,
focus on "replaces" , so you should use AndroidX

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use AndroidX and you should use it. It provides complete back compatibility just as support library does.Actually it is nothing but a major improvement to support library. Android have introduced it in Jetpack and from now on, the new features to support library would be introduced in AndroidX. So you should use it.

Keep in mind, you have to set it up in gradle.properties file as mentioned in the android documentation. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx